# How would you "count" $\omega^\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

$\omega^\omega$ can be seen as the limit of $\omega^n$ which are all countable sets, and is thus countable. For the latter sets, there is an "easy" way list the elements out, but how would you do it for $\omega^\omega$? That is, what would be a bijection from the positive integers to $\omega^\omega$?

Comment: This has come up before on the site. An approach slightly different from tetori's is as follows: One can identify $\omega^2$ with the set of increasing sequences of length 2 (ordered lexicographically), $\omega^3$ with the set of increasing sequences of length 3, etc. But we can identify finite sequences with numbers. For example, we can associate to the sequence $(2,6,20)$ the number $2^2\cdot 3^6\cdot 5^{20}$. This gives us an explicit representation of $\omega^\omega$ as a set of natural numbers. It is used in the partition calculus of countable ordinals.

Comment: Oh right - actually silly me. Now that I have seen the bijection given below, I realised that I even had it written in my notes before. Just that I really didn't realise it last night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f:\omega^\omega\to\Bbb{N}^+$ such that 
$$f(\omega^{n_0}\cdot a_0+\cdots+\omega^{n_k}\cdot a_k):=p_{n_0}^{a_0}p_{n_1}^{a_1}\cdots p_{n_k}^{a_k}.$$
This function is well-defined because of uniqueness of the [Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form) of ordinals, and it is 1-1 function because the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Also, you can prove that this function is onto.